# Android WebView Java-Javascript bridge

Tags: java, javascript, android

I wonder if it's possible to obtain Javascript variable value from Java code. In other words, I've got JS code in WebView and I need to be able to obtain variables from that JS code from WebView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible by installing Java-JS bridge and then injecting JS into page that collects the data and returns it via JS bridge. See this answer: [How to call javascript from Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544671/how-to-call-javascript-from-android/7544818#7544818)

Comment: Just want to add that the bridge broken in android 2.3 and you will require a hack for that version

Comment: @shawndreck is correct. It's unbelievable that this still isn't fixed. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12987

Comment: @shawndreck - I face this same problem in Android 2.3...can u suggest me that hack u were talking about.