# How to return to the a calling activity after successfully login a webpage

Tags: android, cookies

I have a activity which is to ask users to login a webpage. If the users login a webpage successfully, it will return back to another activity I want. 
My problem is after I get the cookies after login, how do I use the cookies to switch to another activity?

```
package com.example.webview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.CookieSyncManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

          //Allow the title bar to show loading progress.
          requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

          WebView webview = new WebView(this);

          setContentView(webview);

          webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

          webview.loadUrl("www.example.com");

          webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
          public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress){
               // Activities and WebViews measure progress with different scales.
               // The progress meter will automatically disappear when we reach 100%
              setProgress(progress * 100);
          }
       });

webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){   
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

  CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();

  // Get the cookie from cookie jar.
  String cookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
        if (cookie == null) {
             return;
        }
        String[] pairs = cookie.split(";");
        for (int i = 0; i < pairs.length; ++i) {
          String[] parts = pairs[i].split("=", 2);
          // If token is found, return it to the calling activity.
          if (parts.length == 2 &&
            parts[0].equalsIgnoreCase("oauth_token")) {
            Intent result = new Intent();
            result.putExtra("token", parts[1]);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, result);
            finish();
         }
      } 
    }
});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a javascript bridge - it will probably accomplish what you want done:

[Android WebView Java-Javascript bridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636409/android-webview-java-javascript-bridge)