# Find hyperlink on webview and click on it

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am new on android, but i want to try to write an app for my friend. He is asking for something, who would let him record a sequence of hyperlinks and repeat it. So far i did a webview program, which shows desired web page ( actually it's wap game ) and i know how to do almost everything, except one thing. 
So, i want to ask if it is possible to designate what for should program search in webview and if app find it - press on it, for example:

Webview shows a page of game with list of possible actions : 
[Cut tree](http://tob.lt/miskas.php?nick=cbbkkr&pass=NTNmODYxNzdiMjQyNjUxf14016ff32cd24f5ebbf0a6d116c4a8a&id=kertu2&ka=MA1&kd=48029), 
[Dig](http://tob.lt/kasimas_kalve.php?nick=cbbkkr&pass=NTNmODYxNzdiMjQyNjUxf14016ff32cd24f5ebbf0a6d116c4a8a&id=mininu&ka=O1&kd)
and etc.

so, I want to know how i can tell program to press on "Cut tree" and then it should automaticly do it and go to pressed webpage.

I hope that someone understood me.

P.S. sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your webview should allow for standard in-page loading of links. If you need data from the link passed to the app, then you need a javascript bridge:

[Android WebView Java-Javascript bridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636409/android-webview-java-javascript-bridge)

Comment: Thanks. All links loads in webview and i need only open it. I don't care about data in opened page. I only need what app would be able to find link and automatically open it. So i think i will go to find something about first option :)