# Android JavaScript Bridge - Trigger Events

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview, android-jsinterface

Probably a simple question, I can call a native function from the JavaScript, for example:

`Android.setVolume(0.7)`

However, I do not know how to trigger (from Android/Java), or handle events (JS) that are not caused by user interaction, for example, alerting the JS when the user's network state changes, the battery gets below a certain point etc.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Actually, just found this answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544671/how-to-call-javascript-from-android/7544818#7544818. The answer is over a year old and is labelled as a hack, is this still the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I do not know how to trigger (from Android/Java), or handle events (JS) that are not caused by user interaction, for example, alerting the JS when the user's network state changes, the battery gets below a certain point etc.

As with the answer you linked to, use `loadUrl()` with a `javascript:` URL, akin to how a bookmarklet works.

> The answer is over a year old and is labelled as a hack, is this still the best way to do it?

I am not completely clear why the author of that answer described it as a hack. Certainly, it's viable and is used a fair bit.