# Call js method from android code

Tags: android

I have a function `drawImage(json, check)` in file test.js. ow I want to call this function from android code. I use `cwv.loadUrl("javascript:test.drawImage("+jsonArray+","+ true+")");`, but this solution doesn't work. How can I call this method from android code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7544818/1276374

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put you JS function not in external file. Insted of it put it in your html file like this:

```
<script>
    function drawImage ()
    {
         // your computataion 
    }
</script>
// or connect your js functions from external file 
<script src="test.js"></script>
```

And then call it from code

```
cwv.loadUrl("javascript:drawImage('"+jsonArray+"','"+ true+"')");
```

And pay attention to single quotation!

And the second mothod was described by Mocialov Boris.

Comment: I must have this method in external file. Can you tell me how can I do that in that way?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Look above