# How to call javascript function and get return value from android?

Tags: java, javascript, android

In this code I return a string. I want to store this string in android activity. How can I call JavaScript function and get return value from android activity?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function gettext(){
            return 'http://192.168.1.11/bmahtml5/images/specs_larg_2.png';
        };
        function button_clicked(){
            window.location='ios:nativecall';
        };
 </script>
```

Comment: may i knw for wt parpose you have to use it??

Comment: Double. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544671/how-to-call-javascript-from-android

Comment: actually i load html page and when i click on some portion when i have to call thi gettext function which returns link of image and i store this image in particular variable and show image in image view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is  a simple :

WebAppInterface.java

```
public class WebAppInterface
 {
        Context mContext;

        /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
        WebAppInterface(Context c)
        {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public void storeText(String text)
        {
            //TODO  save text
            Toast.makeText(mContext, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

WebView webview=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
```

Now  you can  call this method in html ,see it

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function saveFunction(text) 
    {
        Android.storeText(text);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: hi thnks i tried thi code in your script function android.stroretext function callls and in my script function just return string value how can i get this string

Comment: try it ，Can perform actions, but does not return a value.
webview.loadUrl("javascript：gettext()");