# Android - Maintaining SCORM API between two webviews

Tags: javascript, android, api, webview, scorm

I am launching a SCORM compliant course from a webview, which in turn opens another webview containing the course itself. I wish to maintain the API in the original webview to receive response from the webview containing the course once its closed.

I have tried adding two webviews to a page with webview one containing the launch page and webview two containing the course but when I close webview two the data is not updated in webview one.

Comment: It's been a long time that I've worked with SCORM! But I don't see how you can solve your problem without creating a model for the SCORM in your app. Since both WebViews are sandboxes they cannot communicate directly to each other. By creating a JavaScriptInterface you can set the Java objects. This way you create an interface that allows you to let you communicate between your app and a WebView and indirectly (because your app will in between) between two WebViews. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544671/how-to-call-javascript-from-android