# Javascript global module or global variable

Tags: javascript, module, global

I couldn't come up with a better question title, sorry.

My question is, in `he.js` as per https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he/blob/master/he.js , they are using the following code:

```
/*! https://mths.be/he v0.5.0 by @mathias | MIT license */
;(function(root) {

    //...omitted

    var he = {
        'version': '0.5.0',
        'encode': encode,
        'decode': decode,
        'escape': escape,
        'unescape': decode
    };

    // Some AMD build optimizers, like r.js, check for specific condition patterns
    // like the following:
    if (
        typeof define == 'function' &&
        typeof define.amd == 'object' &&
        define.amd
    ) {
        define(function() {
            return he;
        });
    }   else if (freeExports && !freeExports.nodeType) {
        if (freeModule) { // in Node.js or RingoJS v0.8.0+
            freeModule.exports = he;
        } else { // in Narwhal or RingoJS v0.7.0-
            for (var key in he) {
                has(he, key) && (freeExports[key] = he[key]);
            }
        }
    } else { // in Rhino or a web browser
        root.he = he;
    }

}(this));
```

And if you import this into your page as

```
<script src="he.js"></script>
```

You will be able to call the methods in your page as `he.encode(...)`.

My question is, how exactly does it set the variable `he`?

I mean, I can see the

```
    } else { // in Rhino or a web browser
        root.he = he;
    }
}(this));
```

But at the call of `}(this));`, what exactly is `this`?

Comment: `this` will be `window`, - the `this` instance in the time of executing the function, which is the `window`

Comment: @RaraituL oh, I see! Thank you. I thought it might be `document` or something, didn't think of `window`. Thanks again!

Comment: When the he.js loads, it defines a anonymous function (everything between the top level {} in the file). Then it call that function by passing window object. it's done by executing '(this));'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's simplify:

```
;(function(root) {
    ...
}(this));
```

So, we have a function that takes an argument called `root`. This function is being immediately invoked (http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), and we are passing the value `this` to it.

In this context, `this` is your global object. If you are using a browser, your global object will be `window`.

So, if you are indeed using a browser:

```
 root.he = he;
```

is actually the same as:

```
window.he = he;
```

And note, we don't necessarily need to be using a browser, thanks to platforms like Node there are now other contexts where the `this` global object is something other than `window`. That's why the other doesn't specify `window` explicitly and goes through this particular exercise.

Comment: This is cool! I've used a `var globalVariable = (function(){...})();` before, but passing `this` makes it prettier than just using a global constant.