# how to handle the onBackPressed event in android using javascript

Tags: java, android

just like what phonegap does, we can simply override and handle the android backButton using javascript but in this case i don't use phonegap. is there a way to handle that without phonegap?

Answer (score -1):

You can call javascript inside your `onBackPressed()` method:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    WebView.loadUrl("javascript: var result = window.YourJSLibrary.callSomeFunction();
    window.JavaCallback.returnResult(result)");
}
```

for detailed answer check this solution: [How to call javascript from Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544671/how-to-call-javascript-from-android)

Comment: i already have a webview which loads the local html page from asset folder so i can't achieve that :( any other solution?