# android read javascript function int that it passing values

Tags: javascript, android, parsing

Hello all i am new to read javascript i need to call this function...

```
function get_status() {

    $(".alert").remove();

    if (inProcess == false) {
        inProcess = true;

        showProgressBar();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'MYURL.html',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $("#mydata input_txt"),
            success: function(response) {
                inProcess = false;

                if (response['status'] == 1) {
                    location.reload();
                  } else {
                    $("#mydata.modal-body").prepend("<div class='alert alert-warning'>" + response['message'] + "</div>");

                }    
            }        
        });
    }
}
```

i want to call this function of .html file to my android .java file

i found one [Link](http://www.tutorialsavvy.com/2012/12/rhino-javascript-library-for-java.html/) but not able to understand that i how i can use this lib?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: jst call get_status() ; where you want to call and also add this javascript in javascript tag in header

Comment: for more help you can check this following post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544671/how-to-call-javascript-from-android