# Is there an Android app exposing the Tango API via websockets?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, websocket, google-project-tango

Is there an Android app exposing the Tango API via websockets? Would be perfect to explore via JavaScript&more without heavy deploy! cf e.g. https://goocreate.com/blog/1137/it-takes-goo-to-tango/

I'd rather avoid having to (re) learn C# with Unity or C/C++ with the Android SDK as I solely want to focus on the Tango API. I understand the performance will be TERRIBLY downgraded but compared to the time to compile and upload, at first during the exploration phase at least, I believe it's still the better path for my needs.

Suggestions welcomed.

PS: checked alternative e.g. termux + node.js + node-ffi or [Mobile App - Using both Project Tango and Ionic and/or angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38754258/mobile-app-using-both-project-tango-and-ionic-and-or-angular) but that doesn't seem much better.

Comment: Simplest thing might be to write your own app like @Alexander Grau did which also streams the point cloud data. So you will need to use a little C# or C++ at first but once the data is streaming you won't need to go through compile-hell anymore. I'm a JS fanboy so that is what I will probably be doing.

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion: Use my TangoAnywhere App and connect to it via TCP/IP (either on the same device or remote): https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.grauonline.tangoanywhere

Answer (score 0):

Since Google I/O 2017 Google provides Chromium-WebAR https://github.com/googlevr/chromium-webar , a build of Chromium providing access to `getPointCloud()`, `getPickingPointAndPlaneInPointCloud()` and for websockets since it is a web browser.